# How to declare a string as already escaped or 'safe' inside of the view?

Tags: django, django-templates, escaping, django-1.7

My Django Model has two text fields:

```
body = models.TextField()
body_html = models.TextField()
```

The second one gets populated like this:

```
 def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
    self.body_html = "<br />".join(escape(self.body).split("\n"))
    return models.Model.save(self, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update, using=using, update_fields=update_fields)
```

No if I use the body_html in the template I still have to:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ foo.body_html }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

But I don't want to let the designer decide what is safe and what not. So how can I mark this string as 'safe' inside the view or even inside the model to prevent the template from escaping it?

*I know I could use |linebreaksbr in the template, but that's just an example so far. I'm planning to embed pictures in the text as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ought to do it:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

foo = mark_safe(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to django docs:
"escape(text): Returns the given text with ampersands, quotes and angle brackets encoded for use in HTML. The input is first passed through force_text() and the output has mark_safe() applied."
So, 'escaping' the hole string before returning it should be enough.
In case that the model field itsef, when rendered in template, is not correctly displayed, maybe you could try to define a model property that returns escape(self.body_html)